# What does “nichtentheils” mean?

Tags: translation, german-to-english

I found *nichtentheils* in an old 17th century treatise … What does it mean?

Context:

> Folgen etliche Exempla diminutionum, sind aber nichtentheils auff Instrumenten […] zugebrauchen.

Comment: Heute unbekannt. Ich würde " nicht" oder "kaum" vermuten. Hier könnte nur das DWB, Deutsches Wörterbuch, von Grimm helfen.

Comment: Are you sure it's "nichtentheils"? When I look at several results Google Books transcribes at "nichtentheils", what I actually read is "mehrentheils" (for the most part, largely, for the majority of them), and that would make sense in your context, too.

Comment: DWB doesn't know about it, for what it is worth. – A scan from the book would be great.

Comment: See my answer for the source.

Comment: Apparently it occurs in OCRs for multiple sources.

Answer (score 12):

While not completely implausible as an obsolete German word, it's still quite implausible, and I am sure it's not what *nichtentheils* is. If this word had ever existed, it would appear in modern editions with the modernised spelling *nichtenteils*. But this spelling is completely unknown to Google.

I looked at the few Google Books hits for *nichtentheils*. Every single instance is a blatantly obvious OCR error. The actual word is *mehrentheils*, or in modernised spelling *mehrenteils*. In fraktur type, *m* looks similar to *ni*, *e* looks similar to *c* and *r* looks similar to *t*. Apparently a rogue spot over the right half of the initial *m* is enough to put Google's OCR algorithm on the wrong track. Still, presumably this can only happen because *mehrenteils* is a relatively rare word and (again presumably) not built into Google's OCR dictionary.

*Mehrenteils* is still (very rarely) used in formal language, but its synonyms *größtenteils* and *meistens* are vastly more common. The word translates as *mostly* or (quite literally) as *for the most part*.

Obviously it is a very bad idea to rely on OCR for reading old books. You should always use the original text. It really doesn't take long to get used to fraktur.

PS: I just realised that dirkt has made the same observation before in a comment, though he stated it less confidently.

Answer (score 5):

[The source](https://archive.org/stream/dieitalienische00goldgoog#page/n66/mode/2up), a book by Hugo Goldschmidt published in 1892, says *mehrentheils*.  The OCR software used there clearly doesn't handle [Fraktur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraktur) very well.

Answer (score 3):

Supposing the word "nichtentheils" ever existed: It's possible that "nichtentheils" has later been modified to "nichtenteils" as many Names and Words which now are written only with a "t" have been eralier written with "th" like: Thal=Tal.

This contains at least two words we actually use: "nichts" nothing and "Teil" Piece/Part or "nichtens" which is more or less equivalent to the expression "mit Nichten": Which is a kind of negation like "not even". Which seems to fit with the context of your sentence!

Therefore i would assume that "nichtentheils" means something like "not even partly" or "no part of it" or something like this.

Answer (score 2):

Ein zusammengesetztes Wort aus:

- *nichten*: sehr altertümlich für das heutige *nicht* <sup>[(1)](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GN04933#XGN04933)</sup>
- *theils*: alte Schreibweise für *teils* = Wortendung in der Bedeutung von *anteilig* <sup>[(2)](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GT03321#XGT03321)</sup>

Heutzutage würde man *keinesfalls* bzw. *gar nicht* bzw. *überhaupt nicht* verwenden. Siehe auch das im Amtsdeutsch gebräuchliche *mitnichten* <sup>[(3)](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/mitnichten)</sup>.